JDBC connection string to Oracle 9i
Having Oracle 9i I need to connect to it from my C# code.
Having connection string as "jdbc:oracle:thin:USRNAME/passwrd123@89.1.11.105:1521:SERVNAME"
I get an error
fail: AppTran.Controllers.HomeController[0]
Error details: Connection string is not well-formed
fail: AppTran.Controllers.HomeController[0]
Error type: ArgumentException
What's wrong with it?
I changed it to "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 89.1.11.105)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SERVNAME)))"
but no luck.

My Dbeaver connects easily with the string
jdbc:oracle:thin:@89.1.11.105:1521:SID

JDBC via C# ? J stands for Java... or any language running on a Java Virtual Machine.

Ok, let's forget about Java. I use "OracleConnection": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=89.1.11.105)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ZORRO)));User Id=USER1;Password=Angebot;" It still does not work..........

The solution is:

Switch to x86 instead of x64 in VS
Remove Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
Install System.Data.OracleClient
Update HomeController.cs with System.Data.OracleClient usage

Connection string is
"OracleConnection": "Data Source=113.44.31.151:1521/SID;User Id=USR1;Password=PASSw2;Pooling=true;"
